# PHP Registration Issue of Provided Information

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with a referral program website and I have problem..

There are two types when you register. **Applicant** and **Employee**

When you *register* as an  ***Employee***, after the successfully registration, there will be a button there that when you click it, it will display your personal information that you provide during registration..
The information are:

```
Referrer ID
Fullname
Current Position
Contact ID
Email Address
Mobile Number
Member Since
```

When you choose to **register as an employee** provided that you have your employee number already, once you have click the successfully registration button, there will be a page after that and you can see your information.. 
Like this.. Let say

```
Referrer ID: 12345678
Fullname: SHerlock Holmes
Current Position: Programmer
Contact ID: 11001100
Email Address: sherlockholmes@yahoo.com
Mobile Number: 73763-3838
Member Since: 2015-05-07 08:00:20
```

When we talk about the registration as an **employee**. I do not have problems.. 
But

When you *register* as an **Applicant**, I set the **Referrer ID** to *0* because applicant do not have employee number yet.. 
But after the successfully registration as an **applicant** there will be a button there like to **Employee** that when you click it, it will display your personal information that you provide during registration.. I am having problem with this because if you register as an applicant.. 
These are the following information they display..

```
Referrer ID: 0
Fullname: Null/No value.. (Consider I provide Sherlock Holmes as name)
Current Position: No value yet
Contact ID: 11001100
Email Address: sherlockholmes@yahoo.com
Mobile Number: 73763-3838
Member Since: Null/No value..(Consider I provide 2015-05-07 08:00:20 as time of membership)
```

The problem is why my **Fullname** and **Member Since** becomes null or no value when I register as an **Applicant**.. Though, I am expected that this will be having value..

I hope my question is clear so that you can understand.. I am willing to show you my code for registration and the page after the registration where the information displays..

Here's my code for **registration**..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
 include('config.php');
 session_start();

?>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">


</head>

<body>

<form method = "post">
    <table class = "orpRegs" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <td colspan =2>
            <label align="center" style = "border-left:20px;"><h5>Not Yet a     Member?</h5></label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <select name ="ddlGender">
        <option value = "NA"></option>  
        <option value = "M">Mr.</option>
        <option value = "F">Ms.</option>
        </select>
        </td>

        <td align ="left">
             <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtFirstName'])){echo $_POST['txtFirstName'];}?>"  
            required = "true">
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Middle Name</label>
        </td>

        <td align = "left">
        <input type="text" name="txtMiddleName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtMiddleName'])){echo $_POST['txtMiddleName'];}?>" >
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Last name</label>
        </td>

        <td align ="left">
        <input type="text" name="txtLastName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtLastName'])){echo $_POST['txtLastName'];}?>" 
            required="true">
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Suffix</label>
        </td>

        <td align = "left">
        <input type="text" name="txtSuffix" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtSuffix'])){echo $_POST['txtSuffix'];}?>">
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Email Address</label>
        </td>

        <td align = "left">
        <input type="text" name="txtEmail" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtEmail'])){echo $_POST['txtEmail'];}?>" 
            required = "true">
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        <label>Cellphone Number</label>
        </td>

        <td align = "left">
        <input type="text" name="txtCellNum" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtCellNum'])){echo $_POST['txtCellNum'];}?>" 
            required="true" >
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Birthdate</label>
        </td>

        <td align = "left">
        <input type="date" name="txtBirthdate" value="" required="true">
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        function showTextBox() 
        {
                if (document.getElementById('employeeCheck').checked) 
                {
                    document.getElementById('employeeid').style.visibility = 'visible';
                    document.getElementById('employeeidtext').style.visibility = 'visible';
                } 
                else 
                {
                    document.getElementById('employeeid').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    document.getElementById('employeeidtext').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }
                if (document.getElementById('applicantCheck').checked)
                {
                    document.getElementById('employeeid').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    document.getElementById('employeeidtext').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }
        }
        </script>

        <td align = "left">
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="Employee" onClick="showTextBox()" required="true" id ="employeeCheck"><label>Employee</label>
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="Applicant" onClick="showTextBox()" required="true" id ="applicantCheck"><label>Applicant</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label style="visibility:hidden" id ="employeeidtext">Employee ID</label>
        </td>

        <td align = "left">
        <input type="text" name="txtEmployeeId" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtEmployeeId'])){echo $_POST['txtEmployeeId'];}?>"               style="visibility:hidden;width:220px;" id ="employeeid" >
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" required="true"><label>Yes, I agree with our <a href ="http://mainpage.com/Terms/" style="text-decoration:none;" id ="terms" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="image" src="../images/sign_up.png" id ="btnSignUp" value="SIGN ME UP" name ="register" style="border-style:none;">
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</form>

 </body>

 </html>

 <?php  

  if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
       $EmployeeID = $_POST['txtEmployeeId'];
      $Gender =     $_POST['ddlGender'];
        $FirstName =  $_POST['txtFirstName'];
      $MiddleName = $_POST['txtMiddleName'];
       $LastName =   $_POST['txtLastName'];
      $Suffix =     $_POST['txtSuffix'];
       $CellNum =    $_POST['txtCellNum'];
      $Email =      $_POST['txtEmail'];
      $Birthdate =  $_POST['txtBirthdate'];
      $position =   $_POST['position'];
      $isOk = 1;

           if(empty($FirstName))
          {
           // Empty
                $isOk = 0;
                        echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-   size:x-small;">First name is empty!<br></span>';

       }

      if(empty($LastName))
      {
       // Empty
        $isOk = 0;
        $lnameisEmpty = 1;
        echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Last name is empty!<br></span>';
      }

     if(empty($CellNum))
       {
       // Empty
        $isOk = 0;
        echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Mobile number is empty!<br></span>';
      }

      if(empty($Email))
      {
       // Empty
        $isOk = 0;
     echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Email is empty!<br></span>';
      }

       if(empty($Birthdate))
      {
   // Empty
    $isOk = 0;
    echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Birthdate is empty!<br></span>';
  }
  //Validations for letters and spaces
  //preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $string);
        if($isOk == 1)
        {
         if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$/', $FirstName)) 
         {
            // Error
            $isOk = 0;
            echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">First name is invalid!<br></span>';
         } 

        else 
         {
            // Continue
         }

         if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$/', $LastName)) 
         {
            // Error
            $isOk = 0;
            echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Last name is invalid!<br></span>';

         } 

        else 
        {
            //Continue

        }

        if(!empty($Middlename))
        {
         if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$/', $MiddleName))
         {
            // Error
            $isOk = 0;
            echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Middle name is invalid!<br></span>';
         }
        }
        $startOfemail = substr($Email,0,1);
    $pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/";
    if(!preg_match($pattern,$Email))
    {
        // Error email not valid.
        $isOk = 0;
        echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Email is invalid!<br></span>';
    }

    else
    {
        if(!ctype_alpha($startOfemail))
        {
        // Error email should start with letter.
        $isOk = 0;
        echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Email should start with a letter!<br></span>';
        }

        else
        {
        // Continue                                     
        }                           
    }   

        if(!ctype_digit($CellNum)) 
        {
            // Error
            $isOk = 0;
            echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Mobile number is invalid!<br></span>';
        }

         else 
        {
            //Continue
        }

        if(!empty($Suffix))
        {
            if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $Suffix)) 
            {
                // Error
                $isOk = 0;
                echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Suffix is invalid!<br></span>';
            }
            }

        if($position =="Employee")
            {
                if(empty($EmployeeID))
                {
                    // Empty
                    $isOk = 0;
                    echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Employee ID is empty!<br></span>';
                }
                elseif (!ctype_digit($EmployeeID)) 
                {
                    // Error only numbers are accepted
                    $isOk = 0;
                    echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:x-small;">Employee ID is invalid!<br></span>';
                }
                else
                {
                    // Continue
                }
            }

            if($isOk == 1)
            {

                 if($position =="Employee")
                {   

                        if($isOk == 1)
                         {

                             $query = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_contactscf WHERE cf_739 = '$EmployeeID'";
                         $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
                        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
                         {
                             echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:small;">You are Currently Registered in the Sytem. Please log in using your Login details.<br></span>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                 insertNew($EmployeeID,$Gender,$FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$Suffix,$CellNum,$Email,$Birthdate,0);
                        }
                        }
                }

                else
                {
                      $EmployeeID = "0";
                            insertNew($EmployeeID,$Gender,$FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$Suffix,$CellNum,$Email,$Birthdate,1);
                }
            }
               }


    }


    function insertNew($empID, $gender,$fName, $mName, $lName, $suffix, $cellNum, $email, $birthDate, $pos)
    {
       $fName = ucwords($fName);
       preg_replace('/( )+/', ' ', $fName);
       $mName = ucfirst($mName);
        $lName = ucfirst($lName);
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     if($gender == "M")
     {
         $salutation = "Mr";
     }
     else
    {
         $salutation = "Ms";
     }
     if($pos ==1)
     {
         $empID = "0";
     }

     $query = "SELECT 
             vtiger_contactdetails.firstname, 
               vtiger_contactdetails.lastname, 
              vtiger_contactsubdetails.birthday
           FROM vtiger_contactdetails
           INNER JOIN vtiger_contactsubdetails ON 
        vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_contactsubdetails.contactsubscriptionid
           INNER JOIN vtiger_contactscf ON vtiger_contactscf.contactid = vtiger_contactdetails.contactid
           WHERE vtiger_contactdetails.firstname = '$fName'
           AND vtiger_contactdetails.lastname = '$lName'
           AND vtiger_contactsubdetails.birthday = '$birthDate'";

     $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
      if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {
          echo '<span style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:medium;">Account already exists!<br></span>';
       }

      else
     {
    //Get Value of contactid
    $query = "SELECT MAX(crmid) from vtiger_crmentity";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

if($result)
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        $myRows =  mysql_num_rows($result); 
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $contactid = $row[0];
            $newcontactid = $contactid + 1;
            $newcontact_no = "CON"."$newcontactid";

            //Start Inserting Records

            // Insert Data to vtiger_crmentity(parent)
            $insertRec = "INSERT INTO vtiger_crmentity (crmid,  
            smcreatorid,
            smownerid,
            modifiedby,  
            setype,
            createdtime,
            modifiedtime,
            version,
            deleted,
            label) 

            VALUES ('$newcontactid',
            1,
            1,
            1,
            'Contacts',
            '$date',
            '$date',
            0,
            0,
            'Online Referral')";

            $result = mysql_query($insertRec) or die (mysql_error());

            if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                $insertRec = null;
                $result = null;

            // Insert Data to Vtiger_contactdetails  
            $insertRec = "INSERT INTO vtiger_contactdetails (contactid, 
                contact_no, 
                accountid,
                salutation,
                firstname, 
                lastname, 
                mobile, 
                email, 
                emailoptout, 
                notify_owner, 
                isconvertedfromlead)
            VALUES ($newcontactid,
                '$newcontact_no', 
                0,
                '$salutation',   
                '$fName', 
                '$lName', 
                '$cellNum', 
                '$email', 
                0, 
                0, 
                0)";

            $result = mysql_query($insertRec) or die (mysql_error());



            if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                $insertRec = null;
                $result = null;

                //Insert Data to vtiger_contactaddress
                $insertRec = "INSERT INTO vtiger_contactaddress (contactaddressid, 
                    mailingcountry)
                VALUES ($newcontactid, 
                    'Philippines') ";

                $result = mysql_query($insertRec);

                if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                    $insertRec = null;
                    $result = null;

                    //Insert Data to vtiger_contactsubdetails
                    $insertRec = "INSERT INTO vtiger_contactsubdetails (contactsubscriptionid, 
                        birthday, 
                        leadsource, 
                        laststayintouchrequest, 
                        laststayintouchsavedate)
                    VALUES ($newcontactid, 
                        '$birthDate', 
                        'TRM', 
                        0, 
                        0) ";

                    $result = mysql_query($insertRec);

                    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                        $insertRec = null;
                        $result = null;

                        //Insert Data to vtiger_contactscf
                        $insertRec ="INSERT INTO vtiger_contactscf (contactid,
                            cf_739,
                            cf_709,
                            cf_703,
                            cf_705,
                            cf_1069)
                        VALUES ($newcontactid,
                            '$empID',
                            '$gender',
                            '$mName',
                            '$suffix',
                            0.0)";

                        $result = mysql_query($insertRec);

                        if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                            $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'] = $empID; 
                            $_SESSION['SESS_CONID'] = $newcontactid;
                            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRSTNAME'] = $fName;
                            $_SESSION['SESS_LASTNAME'] = $lName;
                            $_SESSION['SESS_CONTACT_NO'] = $newcontact_no;
                            $_SESSION['SESS_MOBILE'] = $cellNum;
                            $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $email;
                            $_SESSION['SESS_BDAY'] = $birthDate;

                            //Email registrant of his or her account details(firstname, lastname, birthdate)
                                   mailRegistration($empID,$fName,$lName,$birthDate,$email);
                                 //Direct to Welcome Page for New Registrants

                                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>            
                                window.location.href='/successReg.php';
                                    </SCRIPT>");

                            }
                         }              
                     }
                }
                }
            }
        }
            else 
            {
            echo "Something went wrong!";
            }
        }


    }

?>
```

Here's my code for **personal information**..

```
<?php
/**** Start Session ****/
include_once '../function/auth_emp.php';
/**** End ****/

/**** Redirects automatically to index ****/
header("Refresh: 15 * 60; url=index.php");
/**** End ****/

/**** authentication ****/
//require_once('../function/auth_emp.php');
/**** End ****/

$empid = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'];
$bdate = $_SESSION['SESS_BDAY'];



/**** Database connection ****/
require_once('../include/config.php');
/**** End ****/


include'../GlobalConstants.php';

include_once ('../refer/updateInfo.php');

mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("ERR_COULD_NOT_SEE_DB");
if($empid == 0)
{
$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_FNAME'];
$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_LNAME'];
$bdate = $_SESSION['SESS_BDAY'];

$qry= "SELECT vtiger_contactdetails.firstname,
          vtiger_contactdetails.contact_no, 
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_703,
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_715, 
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_717,
          vtiger_contactdetails.email,
          vtiger_contactdetails.lastname, 
          vtiger_contactdetails.mobile,
          vtiger_contactdetails.contactid,
          vtiger_crmentity.createdtime
       FROM vtiger_contactdetails 
       INNER JOIN vtiger_contactscf 
       ON vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_contactscf.contactid
       INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity
       ON vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid
       INNER JOIN vtiger_contactsubdetails
       ON vtiger_contactsubdetails.contactsubscriptionid= vtiger_contactdetails.contactid
       WHERE vtiger_contactdetails.firstname = '".$fname."'
       AND vtiger_contactdetails.lastname =  '".$lname."'
       AND vtiger_contactsubdetails.birthday = '".$bdate."'";   

$result = mysql_query($qry);
}
else
{
$qry= "SELECT vtiger_contactdetails.firstname,
          vtiger_contactdetails.contact_no, 
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_703,
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_715, 
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_717,
          vtiger_contactdetails.email,
          vtiger_contactdetails.lastname, 
          vtiger_contactdetails.mobile,
          vtiger_contactdetails.contactid,
          vtiger_crmentity.createdtime
       FROM vtiger_contactdetails 
       INNER JOIN vtiger_contactscf 
       ON vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_contactscf.contactid
       INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity
       ON vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid
       WHERE vtiger_contactscf.cf_739 = '".$empid."'";

$result = mysql_query($qry);
}
if($result)
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)> 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $contact_no = $row['contact_no'];
        $fname = $row['firstname'];
        $mname = $row['cf_703'];
        $lname = $row['lastname'];
        $mobile = $row['mobile'];
        $pos = $row['cf_715'];
        $program = $row['cf_717'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $conid = $row['contactid'];
        $memberdate = $row['createdtime'];

    }
}

$erp = "ERP";
/**** Stores the firstname and lastname in the session ****/
$_SESSION['SESS_EMP_ID'] = $empid;
$_SESSION['SESS_CONID'] = $conid;
$_SESSION['SESS_FIRSTNAME'] = $fname;
$_SESSION['SESS_MIDDLENAME'] = $mname;
$_SESSION['SESS_LASTNAME'] = $lname;
$_SESSION['SESS_MOBILE'] = $mobile;
$_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $email;
$_SESSION['SESS_POSITION'] = $pos;
$_SESSION['SESS_GEN'] =$erp;
$_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
 ?>



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Referrer Personal Information -->
            <center>
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <br>
                <hr class="between" width="70%">
                <form name="updatein"  method="post">
                        <div class="referrerinformation"> 
                            <div class="referrerinfohere">
                                    <div class="firsttdr">
                                    <h4 class="ua">User Agreement</h4>
 <p align="justify">You agree to provide true, accurate, and complete information on all registration and other 
 forms you 
 access on the Site or any data sent to us related in updating your information to maintain its truthfulness, 
 accuracy,
 and completeness. You must not provide misleading information about your location and the information of the 
 one you 
 are referring. You must not register for more than one Referrer’s Account without written permission from us. 
 Solely 
 for purposes of the foregoing sentence, ’You’ means you, any member of your immediate family, and any entity
 directly 
 or indirectly controlled by you or by any member of your immediate family.</p>
                                    </div>

                        <div class="secondtdr">
                                    <h4 class="ua">Referrer Personal Information</h4>
 <div class="referrerid">
     <p align="left">Referrer ID</p>
     <input type="number" name="label:Referrer_Emp_ID" readOnly="true" value="<?php echo $empid; ?>">
                                            </div>


 <div class="fnamep">
   <p align="left">Fullname</p>
   <input type="text" name="cont" value="<?php echo $fname." ".$mname." ".$lname; ?>" readOnly="true">
 </div>

 <div class="position">
   <p align="left">Current Position</p>
   <input type="text" name="cont" value="<?php echo $pos; ?>" readOnly="true">
 </div>


 <div class="contactid">
   <p align="left">Contact ID</p>
   <input type="number" name="cont" value="<?php echo $conid; ?>" readOnly="true">
 </div>


 <div class="emailad">
   <p align="left">Email Address:</p>
   <input type="email" name="cont" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" readOnly="true">
 </div>


 <div class="mobilenum">
   <p align="left">Mobile Number:</p>
   <input type="number" name="cont" value=<?php echo $mobile; ?> readOnly="true">
 </div>


 <div class="membersc">
   <p align="left">Member Since</p>
   <input type="text" name="cont" value="<?php echo $memberdate; ?>" readOnly="true">
 </div>

                                            <div class="container">
 <center><a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Edit Personal Information</a></center>
                                            <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">

                                            <!--head-->
                            <header class="popupHeader">
             <span class="header_title">Referrer Personal Information</span>
                <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
 </header>

                                                <!--section-->
                                                <section class="popupBody">
         <div class="table">

          <!-- Social Login -->
             <p align="left"><strong>EDIT INFORMATION HERE</strong></p><br>

 <div class="tabletoedit">


 <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]);?>" method="post"> 
 <br>
 <div class="empnum">
 <p align="left">Employee Number</p><br>
 <input type="number" name="txt_EmpID" required="true" value="<?php echo $empid; ?>"
 <?php
                                        if($empid != 0)
                                        {
                                         echo "readonly";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        >
                    </div>

 <div class="fnamep">
                    <p align="left">Fullname</p>
                    <input type="text" name="cont" value="<?php echo $fname." ".$mname." ".$lname; ?>" 
                    readOnly="true">
 </div>

 <div class="position">
 <p align="left"> Current Position</p>
 <input type ="text" name ="txt_CurrentPos" value="<?php echo $pos; ?>" required>
 </div>


 <div class="contactid">
 <p align="left">Contact ID</p>
 <input type="number" name="cont" value="<?php echo $conid; ?>" readOnly="true">
 </div>


 <div class="emailad">
 <p align="left">Email Address</p>
 <input type="email" name ="txt_Email" value ="<?php echo $email; ?>"  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" title="youremail@domain.com" required>
 </div>


 <div class="mobilenum">
 <p align="left">Mobile Number</p>
 <input type ="number" name ="txt_Mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>" required>
 </div>

 <div class="action_btns">

    <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit1" value="update"
    style="width:237px;margin-top:0%;">  


  </div>
  </form>

                </div> <!-- table to edit end-->

            </div> <!-- table div end-->

            <div class="updatereminder">
 <p align="justify">
                <strong>UPDATING INFORMATION</strong><br><br>
 You can only edit/change/update the following information:<br>
             Employee Number (if none)
             Email Address
             Mobile Number
             Current Position<br><br>
 In the event that the Employee number was mistakenly submitted during registration, kindly send us an 
 email 
 stating your Full Name and your correct employee number using our online contact form within this 
 website.   
 Please inform us immediately.
 <br>
                    <br>
 Updating your personal information is covered by the User Agreement and the Terms and Conditions in 
 using the 
 Convergys Online Referral Program. Sanction/s shall be imposed to users who deliberately provide false 
 information.
                </p>
        </div>
                                                </section>
                                        </div> <!-- referrerinfohere div end here-->
                                    </div> <!-- referrerinfomration div end here-->
                             </form> <!-- FORM updatein end here-->

                             <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

                                        $(function(){
                                          // Calling Login Form
                                          $("#login_form").click(function(){
 $(".social_login").hide();
 $(".user_login").show();
 return false;
                                          });

                                          // Calling Register Form
                                          $("#register_form").click(function(){
 $(".social_login").hide();
 $(".user_register").show();
 $(".header_title").text('Register');
 return false;
});

 // Going back to Social Forms
 $(".back_btn").click(function(){
 $(".user_login").hide();
 $(".user_register").hide();
 $(".social_login").show();
 $(".header_title").text('Login');
 return false;
 });

 })
</script>
</div> <!-- twelve column div ends here-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code ? please

Comment: Yes your question is clear, thanks ! ;)

Comment: Did you see my code at the bottom of my question??

Comment: When I register as an **Applicant**, I am having null to fullname and Member since which supposed to have value.

Comment: Did you checked in your database that the **Applicant** have these information ? And for information, you need to place the `session_start();` before the `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: Yes, Once I register as an Applicant, I can see the data in database.. But when I log-out the page.. Then Log-in, I can now see the **Full name and Member since**

Comment: Even I place the `<?php
 include('config.php');
 session_start();
 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning, I tried to register, and Still, I get null values..

Comment: I do not have problems with **Employee**, Just the _applicant_..

Comment: If I understand ok then, these values are null in the first login? But they are in db, and when you re-login they are outputted ok?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `personal information` page ? please I think your problem is due to a $_SESSION or something like that.

Comment: Yes, Exactly @Alariva. That is what happening, When I try to register as an **applicant**, when I go to `personal information` page, **null values** for Fullname and Member since, But when I logout and Try to re-login they are outputted..

Comment: Ok.. I will add the `personal information page` @zilongqiu

Comment: @zilongqiu, take a look to my code above.

Comment: @Shared Thanks man i got the issue.

Comment: @zilongqiu, I don't know what's the problem of not showing the **full name** and **member since** when you register as an **Applicant**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it:
    
`$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_FNAME']; // --> NOT DEFINE IN REGISTRATION`
    `$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_LNAME']; // --> NOT DEFINE IN REGISTRATION`
To:

`$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_FNAME']; //`
    `$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_LNAME']; //`

Comment: I think this will not work because `$_SESSION['SESS_FNAME']` and `$_SESSION['SESS_LNAME']` are not defined.

Comment: Solution

In the personnal page just replace this

$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_FNAME'];
$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_LNAME']; 
By this

$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRSTNAME'];
$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_LASTNAME'];

Comment: Thanks@another person anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you never define `$_SESSION['SESS_EMP_FNAME']` and `$_SESSION['SESS_EMP_LNAME']` in your **registration** page.

**Errors in `personnal page`**

```
if($empid == 0)
{
$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_FNAME']; // --> NOT DEFINE IN REGISTRATION
$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_LNAME']; // --> NOT DEFINE IN REGISTRATION
$bdate = $_SESSION['SESS_BDAY'];

$qry= "SELECT vtiger_contactdetails.firstname,
          vtiger_contactdetails.contact_no, 
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_703,
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_715, 
          vtiger_contactscf.cf_717,
          vtiger_contactdetails.email,
          vtiger_contactdetails.lastname, 
          vtiger_contactdetails.mobile,
          vtiger_contactdetails.contactid,
          vtiger_crmentity.createdtime
       FROM vtiger_contactdetails 
       INNER JOIN vtiger_contactscf 
       ON vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_contactscf.contactid
       INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity
       ON vtiger_contactdetails.contactid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid
       INNER JOIN vtiger_contactsubdetails
       ON vtiger_contactsubdetails.contactsubscriptionid= vtiger_contactdetails.contactid
       WHERE vtiger_contactdetails.firstname = '".$fname."'
       AND vtiger_contactdetails.lastname =  '".$lname."'
       AND vtiger_contactsubdetails.birthday = '".$bdate."'";   

$result = mysql_query($qry);
}
```

**Solution**

In the `personnal page` just replace this

```
$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_FNAME'];
$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_LNAME'];
```

By this

```
$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRSTNAME'];
$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_LASTNAME'];
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: So I will just paste it `$fname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_FNAME']; // --> NOT DEFINE IN REGISTRATION
$lname = $_SESSION['SESS_EMP_LNAME'];` at Registration Page?